# 64 bit driver not working in 64 bit Windows 7/8

Tags: windows, usb, 64-bit, driver

I own the following device:

Ethernet USB 2.0 Lan Network Card RJ45 Adapter 100 Mbps For Laptop PC

It is basically a USB to LAN converter.
I can confirm that it works with Windows 7 32 bits, but not with Windows 7 64 bits or Windows 8 64 bits.

I have the seller driver cd which has specific 64 bit drivers (HG20F9_Win7_64bit_Driver_v5.14.7.0_WHQL) but the following behaviour is experienced:

trying to tell windows to browse to the driver folder

> windows could not find driver software for your device

trying to give windows the direct location of the inf file

> the folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver
>   for your device. if the folder contains a driver, make sure it is
>   designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems

it appears that ocassionaly I can link the .inf and it will allow using it but will throw the warning below, and end up with a "code 10" error after completion

> Installing this device driver is not recommended because Windows
>   cannot verify that it is compatible with your hardware. If the driver
>   is not compatible, your hardware will not work correctly and your
>   computer might become unstable or stop working completely. Do you want
>   to continue installing this driver?

[product page](http://coisasuteis.net/en/lan/45-ethernet-usb-20-lan-network-card-rj45-adapter-100-mbps-for-laptop-pc.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where a 32 bit device could not open a 32 bit file.

The device was shown as (portable Device) instead of unknown, and could not run the inf file.

Steps to solve this:

- Uninstalling the driver completely (from Device Manager right click and uninstall)
- unplugging it and re-plugging it back in.
- The device should be shown under Unknown
- Upgrade the device using the inf you want

Answer (score 1):

it appears that the device was malfunctioning, being assigned the wrong category (usb) while it should be just a basic "unrecognized device".

the solution was to try the "pick-inf-file-directly" approach several times until I got the actual device driver pop up instead of the x64 message (finally worked when the device appeared under the unrecognized devices category).

I still got the "windows cannot verify..." message but continuing was the way to go.

after a bit of fiddling around I found that the device works, but I just have to keep it completely immobilized, otherwise it will disappear completely from device manager.

I guess I was looking for a crazy workaround, such as messing with the .inf file or force-signing the driver files, while in my particular case, it was just a plain hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was plugging in my Playstation 2 camera into the USB 2.0 slot and that switching it to the usb 3.0 or 3.1 solved the problem of the device not being recognized :D